# Can I still unlock the riptide style even though it isn't chapter 2 season 1 anymore?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have searched it up but there are millions of answers and i've tried a lot of them. I can't figure it out though.

Comment: They do put old skins up for sale in the item shop, and Riptide will come around from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

**No, after the season is over, you can’t unlock any more styles from that season**, or any cosmetics, too. Epic did this in order that people would try to play a lot more and have the “get it before it’s gone” mentality about items. It’s a simple marketing strategy that works great, especially in video games.